# Adding patent number as Tag verification

Tags: feature-request, tags

I feel that for new question we can have TAG system verification wherein if a question body or title contains any number more than 4 digit a tag auto verification pop-up [currently seen as red square for errors] should be created.

this will help to aware user that a patent number should be tagged.